# How to disable code Optimization with gyp?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, node-gyp, gyp

I have a gyp generated project that produces the following error in MSVC2013:
I have the following error in MSVC2013: error D8016: '/O2' and '/RTC1' command-line options are incompatible.

Therefore I tried to turn off optimizations trying:
'Optimization': 'd',   # no message
'Optimization': 'Disabled',   # warning message
'AdditionalOptions': ['/Od'] # no message
and none of them works.

How can I set /Od instead of the default /O2 in gyp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node-gyp`  loads a `common.gypi` file with compiler settings before `binding.gyp`. You can override MSVC settings in your target  with a `configuration.Release.msvs_settings.VCCLCompilerTool' dictionary:

```
  'configuration': { 'Release': { 'msvs_settings': { 'VCCLCompilerTool': {
      'Optimization': 0
  }}}}
```

See https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/26#issuecomment-7296389